# Visualizing data from Neoj4 database in real-time in a web app

Tags: node.js, neo4j, real-time

I have a python program which creates data that will continuously create new data and store in a database. This data needs to be visualized in a web app and I'd like to do this in real-time, with the visualization continuously being updated as new data comes in. I've figured out how to do this in MongoDB with a "changestream" using the mongodb Node package but I'm interested in using Neo4J instead, since the data is network-based. How would I go about doing this?